# Different collation between master database and application database

Tags: sql-server

I just installed SQL Server 2019. Unfortunately I didn't notice the collation while installing. Following are the collations:

```
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.databases
```

| name | collation_name |
| --- | --- |
| master | Latin1_General_CI_AS |
| tempdb | Latin1_General_CI_AS |
| model | Latin1_General_CI_AS |
| msdb | Latin1_General_CI_AS |
| ReportServer | Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS |
| ReportServerTempDB | Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS |
| ApplicationDB | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |

```
use ApplicationDB    
GO 
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'Collation')
```

> SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

The application recommends that the database to be SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, but they're unsure about the system databases as they're not database experts. Will there be any consequences. We would be running SSRS reports to pull data from the application database. Will this be an issue? I'm confused

Comment: afaik, the collation on system databases shouldn’t effect the behavior of your applicationDB and it’s functionality. As long as your reads and writes are constrained within the database then you are fine.

Comment: @SivaDasari TempDB uses instance collation, and that [might cause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/161012/4511) unexpected [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21332105/503046).

Comment: @vonPryz you are right and thank you for sharing those sources. Which needs to be verified from the application whether explicit COLLATE is specified for tempdb operations.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved using database repair script. I have faced similar kind of issue. Try using provided link

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/change-collation-at-instance-level-through-rebuild-databases-in-sql-server-2017